# When Serializing A VB.Net Class to XML how do you alter the hierarchy?

Tags: vb.net, xml-serialization

I have created a class from and xsd using xsd.exe. The VB.Net class is fine. I have to use this class to create a file which contains multiple versions of the class.
So if my code generated class is called "Profile" I want a file which is structured as follows:

```
<Profiles>
<FILEFROM>ID1</FILEFROM>
<Profile>
  .
  .
</Profile>
<Profile>
  .
  .
</Profile>
```

I have created a class (ProfilesClass) and included a property (Profile) which is an array of the Profile Class, but I get an extra level in my XML when serialized. Here's the class definition:

```
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Profiles", [Namespace]:="http/webaddress/TravelProfile", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public Class ProfilesClass
Private _Profiles() As ProfileType
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Profile", IsNullable:=False), _
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("Profiles", Isnullable:=False)> _
 Public Property Profiles() As ProfileType()
    Get
        Return _Profiles
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ProfileType())
        _Profiles = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

This means that the XML, when serialised is this:

```
<Profiles>
    <Profiles>
        <Profile>
        </Profile>        
    </Profiles>
</Profiles>
```

How can I remove one of the levels of "Profiles"